# How to create loops in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I need to show 2 `div` elements, one after another, in a loop.

HTML
    Text
    Other text

jQuery

```
$('#1').animate({opacity:0},500)
    .animate({opacity:1},500)
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({opacity:0},500);
```

What should go here in between? So 1st we run animation for #1 and only then start animation for #1 DIV

```
$('#2').animate({opacity:0},500)
    .animate({opacity:1},500)
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({opacity:0},500);
```

And how to make infinite loop out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an infinite loop you could put each div's animation in its own function and then call that function from the complete callback of the end of the other animation. (Easier to show than explain:)

```
function do1() {
   $('#1').animate({opacity:0},500)
       .animate({opacity:1},500)
       .delay(2000)
       .animate({opacity:0},500,function() {
            do2();
       });
}
function do2() {
   $('#2').animate({opacity:0},500)
          .animate({opacity:1},500)
          .delay(2000)
          .animate({opacity:0},500,function() {
            do1();
       });
}

​do1();​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/HQ5ys/1

Or just put the code in a single function that calls itself:

```
function myAnimate() {
   $('#1').animate({opacity:0},500)
       .animate({opacity:1},500)
       .delay(2000)
       .animate({opacity:0},500,function() {
          $('#2').animate({opacity:0},500)
             .animate({opacity:1},500)
             .delay(2000)
             .animate({opacity:0},500,function() {
                myAnimate();
          });
}

​myAnimate();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/HQ5ys/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback of `animate()`. The callback will run when the animations finish.

```
$('#one').animate({}, 'fast', function(){ 
    //Callback 
    $('#two').animate({ });
});
```

Comment: Simplest case, put everything inside a function and `setInterval(func, 1000); // Run every 1s`. But you might want to look into `queue()` and `dequeue()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use when-then function of jQuery for this.

```
$.when(
    function(){
        $('#1').animate({opacity:0},500)
            .animate({opacity:1},500)
        .delay(2000)
        .animate({opacity:0},500);})
.then(function(){
    $('#2').animate({opacity:0},500)
    .animate({opacity:1},500)
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({opacity:0},500);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the complete callback function like:

```
setInterval(function () {
$("#1").animate({opacity:0}, 500, function() {
  $("#2").animate({opacity:0},500);
}), 5000); //runs every 5 secs
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to loop this, so it repeats over and over again?